# Cython: how can I set the attribute of a cdef class?

Tags: python, cython

In Cython, in order to have a class that has C methods (i.e. methods defined using the keywords `cpdef` or `cdef`), one needs to define a `cdef` class: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html

Does such a class have a method to access one of its attributes by a string representing the name of the attribute (the corresponding method would be `setattr()` in standard Python)?

Comment: I believe that if it's a `cdef public class`, Cython will incur the overhead to add Python properties that should let you use the Python built-in `setattr` (it's not a **method**, it's a built-in Python **function**).

Comment: @AlexMartelli Thanks so much! I suppose you do not care about internet points?

Comment: If by "internet points" you mean StackOverflow reputation, sure I do care -- let me make this an answer to get a chance for upvote and accept... I do erroneously sometimes "answer in comments", sorry!).

Comment: At the bottom of the corresponding Cython tutorial page (http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) is described how "Properties can be declared to expose dynamic attributes to Python-space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if it's a `cdef public class`, `Cython` will incur the overhead needed to add Python properties that should let you use the Python built-in `setattr` (it's not a **method**, it's a built-in Python **function**).

Comment: The public keyword in Cython serves to expose the class to C, not to Python. When it is used, an additional header file .h is created.